# How do I get the name of a WP admin submenu?

Tags: wordpress

I am working with WP 3.5 and have used the following line to add a sub menu:

```
add_submenu_page('lingo_menu', 'Manage Units', 'Manage Units', 'manage_options', 'lingo_manage_units_menu', 'lingo_manage_units');
```

And, of course I have a function called 'lingo_manage_units()'.

I would like to redirect all my sub menu calls through one single function where a switch statement will determine what to do. However, I am not sure how to get the name of the submenu page that was called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get it from the `page` GET variable:

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
```